# How to Change Django Homepage with Your Custom Design?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I am trying to change django default homepage with my custom design, but it's not working. I Try a lot but still the same issue, I am not Understanding what is the issue, it's working perfect on my local server, But I am implementing Django app on Live server, Please let me know where I am mistaking.

here is my django default `urls.py` file...

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('mainadmin/admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    url(r'^myadmin/', include('myadmin.urls')),
    url('', include('homepanel.urls')),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: you need to change the order of path's. By default Django took first matched URL and execute the related view.

Comment: What do you mean by *default home page*? You meant Admin page?

Comment: i changed `admin` url, but still it's opening `domain.com/admin` but my path is `domain.com/mainpage/admin`, and by default it's opening `Django` default homepage, but there are a new page for `domain.com`.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways you can change the admin panel of the your django website.
[here](https://medium.com/@adriennedomingus/adding-custom-views-or-templates-to-django-admin-740640cc6d42) is the article which will tell you how can you implement that